# What is the difference between Mathematics SE and Mathematics Meta?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, se-sites

As the title sounds, what is the difference between Mathematics Stack Exchange and Mathematics Meta?

Comment: [Have you read this?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is covered in the help centre at length.

Comment: Also, the name "meta" itself is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Not to everyone. Ask 20 random people to define it.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Calculus is covered at length in calculus books; we don't close all calculus questions because of this.

Comment: @MiceElf However, we do strive to concentrate knowledge in one place through the duplicate mechanism. However, closing as a duplicate of the help centre is impossible. Whence my closevote.

Comment: I had a question closed because it was covered in the wiki. One person answered it and helped me a lot. Once I had sufficient Rep, I edited the wiki to make the help clearer. Sometimes the user reads the help page and *still* doesn't know. That's why we have questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main site, [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), is meant for questions (and answers) about *mathematics*, as generally outlined [in the Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> Mathematics Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related fields.  We welcome questions about:
>
> - Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems.
> - Mathematical problems such as one might come across in a course or textbook. ...
> - Solving mathematical puzzles.
> - Software that mathematicians use....

---

The meta site, [Meta Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/), is meant for questions (and answers) about *Mathematics Stack Exchange* (and the underlying Stack Exchange architecture), as generally outlined [in the Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

> Meta Mathematics Stack Exchange is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Mathematics Stack Exchange rather than discussing math itself.

(That there is a mathematical subject called [*metamathematics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamathematics) may make this somewhat confusing.)